# Error installing Imagick on MacOS Catalina

Tags: imagemagick, macos-catalina

Trying to get php/imagick working on my mac running OS 10.15.3 (Catalina) using brew.
I installed Php (7.4.3)
I installed imagemagic ( 7.0.9-23)
Then when I pecl install imagick
I get:

```
       545 $ pecl install imagick
    downloading imagick-3.4.4.tgz ...
    Starting to download imagick-3.4.4.tgz (253,434 bytes)
    .....................................................done: 253,434 bytes
    ERROR: failed to write /usr/local/pear/docs/imagick/examples/.tmppolygon.php:
 copy(/usr/local/pear/docs/imagick/examples/.tmppolygon.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

The folder exists and is empty and has permissions

```
drwxrwxr-x  6 root  admin   192B Aug 29 08:46 /usr/local/pear/docs/imagick/examples
```

Frustrating that the installation fails because an example file won't load.  The message sounds like it can't read the source but I'm not sure.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by running sudo pecl install instead of just pecl.  That got partway, and then encountered missing readline lib which produced a error message about version number.  That is fixed by brew upgrade awk.  Looks like it all succeeded.